# Meaning of "普段ならまだしも、さすがに今は少しばかり状況が違う"

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of 普段ならまだしも、さすがに今は少しばかり状況が違う

> 「って、ヴェル！？」
>
> 思い切り、まるで飛び付くように抱きついてくるヴェル。
>
> 「み、みんな見てますけれどもっ」
>
> 普段ならまだしも、さすがに今は少しばかり状況が違う。俺の叫びで気がついたのか、ヴェルは周囲をそっと見回した。

The two possible definitions that I think could match this usage from Daijisen's

1. あることを認めはするが、特定の条件下では、それと相反する感情を抱くさま。そうは言うものの。それはそうだが、やはり。「味はよいが、これだけ多いと さすがに 飽きる」「非はこちらにあるが、一方的に責められると さすがに 腹が立つ」
2. 予想・期待したことを、事実として納得するさま。また、その事実に改めて感心するさま。なるほど、やはり。「一人暮らしは さすがに 寂しい」「 さすがに （は）ベテランだ」

Part of my confusion stems from the nuance of まだしも.　The definition from [link](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/208298/m0u/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A0%E3%81%97%E3%82%82/) says `まだを強めた言い方。よくもないがそれでも`

My intuition makes me feel like it's the first usage because the second one doesn't sound quite right. he says that under normal circumstances that it "wouldn't be that big of a deal/he wouldn't have minded that much / etc." but that the current situation is a bit different than normal ( referring to the fact that they are currently the centre of attention of many of people there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition regarding the usage of 「さすがに」 is correct.

The action taken by ヴェル would have been "acceptable" to the speaker, if not fantastic, had s/he done it under ordinary circumstances.  This time, however, the speaker was taken by surprise given the presence of many people around them.

「～～ならまだしも」 means "it would have been ok if ~~ (or 'ok in a ~~ situation')".

One meaning/usage of 「まだ」 is to express one's opinion that something is "comparatively good, if not great".

See definiton  二-6 here:

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%9C%AA%E3%81%A0-435851#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89